# draw text to center of the image using PIL

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library

I have a few stings I would like to draw to imagea. the thing is that I want each string to be displayed in the middle of each image. how do I do it? or how can I know the length in pixels of a string (giving ofcourse the font)?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

PIL font's do have a getsize method which you can use to get width and height of font, did you try that?
e.g.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

fontFile = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf"
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontFile, 10)
text="anurag"
print font.getsize(text)
assert font.getsize(text)[0]*2 == font.getsize(text*2)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could find an implementation of this at http://tools.jedutils.com/tools/center-text-image

You could use that page for creating the image right there instead of implementing the routine yourself but the code is included on the page too.

Following Nicole's advise

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import StringIO

filter_dict = {
    'BLUR' : ImageFilter.BLUR,
    'CONTOUR' : ImageFilter.CONTOUR,
    'DETAIL' : ImageFilter.DETAIL,
    'EDGE_ENHANCE' : ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE,
    'EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE' : ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE,
    'EMBOSS' : ImageFilter.EMBOSS,
    'FIND_EDGES' : ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES,
    'SMOOTH' : ImageFilter.SMOOTH,
    'SMOOTH_MORE' : ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE,
    'SHARPEN' : ImageFilter.SHARPEN
}

def get_font_full_path(font_path,font_name):
    ext = '.TTF' if font_name.upper() == font_name else ".ttf"
    return font_path + font_name + ext

def create_image(font_name, font_size, font_color, width, height, back_ground_color, text, img_type="JPEG", image_filter=None):
    font_full_path = get_font_full_path(font_path,font_name)
    font  =  ImageFont.truetype ( font_full_path, font_size )

    im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
    draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
    text_x, text_y = font.getsize(text)
    x = (width - text_x)/2
    y = (height - text_y)/2
    draw.text ( (x,y), text, font=font, fill=font_color )

    if image_filter:
        real_filter = filter_dict[image_filter]
        im = im.filter(real_filter)
    im.save ( "sample.jpg", format=img_type )
```

`

Comment: It's helpful to also summarize the implementation in case the website you have linked to goes down.